# Writing to Storage on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Im working on a Windows Phone 8 app that has a subscribe to podcast feature.
While the app is running, the user can click a subscribe button and the show they are viewing is added to a `List<Show>` that is maintained in the App.xaml.cs file. 
When the app is deactivated, I attempt to write the data in that `List<Show>` to json and then persist it to disk in a directory in the LocalFolder. Here the code that I have:

```
 public async Task<bool> SaveSubscriptions(List<Show> subs)
        {
            try
            {
                string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subs, Formatting.Indented);
                Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Subscriptions");
                using (Stream writer = await folder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("subscriptions.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
                {
                    writer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                    await writer.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

You can see that Im trying to write the data to a file called subscriptions.json inside of a directory called Subscriptions. The Subscriptions directory is created when the App starts up if its not already there. This part is working properly.
The issue Im having is with GetFolderAsync.
As soon as I hit that code in the debugger and try to step over it, the app exits providing no other info. I dont hit the catch statment. The app just quits. Im really puzzled. This seems like its pretty straight forward. Am I missing something silly?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran into a similar problems where my application was closing before it has a chance to write the file to local storage in the deactivated event. The reason in my case was because of the asynchronous operation in the deactivated event.

Since the application was spinning up another thread essentially to do the work it would get the the async operation and return control back to the main thread while the task completed. The main thread would then continue closing. A way to work around this problem is to simply create a synchronous operation that forces the main thread wait until the operation is complete (exclude the async/await syntax).

A better way and how I handle it in my apps is to **save the list asynchronously as it is updated rather than waiting to do so within the deactivated event.**  That way you aren't relying on the deactivated event for saving data core to the operation of your application.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you should not use `ApplicationData.Current` as it is only accessible for non-signed `.xap`s (not from Marketplace). As a result after release application will crash.

Instead - use `IsolatedStorageFile`. Sample snippet:

```
public async Task<bool> SaveSubscriptions(List<Show> subs)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            try
            {
                string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subs, Formatting.Indented);
                Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.CreateFile("Subscriptions\\subscriptions.json"))
                {
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```